# AdaptiveConstraints class is not defined in Flutter's adaptive_breakpoints package

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently setting up a new Flutter app, and I'd like to use the [`adaptive_breakpoints` package](https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_breakpoints) to specify which components to be shown on a specific device size (e.g. small or large).

I've tried to follow closely with the [package documentation examples,](https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_breakpoints) which utilizes the `AdaptiveContainer` class to my own code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:adaptive_breakpoints/adaptive_breakpoints.dart';

class Taskbar extends StatelessWidget {
  const Taskbar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomAppBar(
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: IconTheme(
          data: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              AdaptiveContainer(
                adaptiveConstraints: AdaptiveConstraints(xs: true),
              ),
              IconButton(
                tooltip: 'Open navigation menu',
                icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                tooltip: 'Search',
                icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                tooltip: 'Favorite',
                icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

However, I got this error instead, saying that the `AdaptiveContainer` class is not defined. Is the Flutter library incomplete or did I miss some steps for setting it up?

```
lib/components/taskbar.dart:16:38: Error: The method 'AdaptiveConstraints' isn't defined for the class 'Taskbar'.
 - 'Taskbar' is from 'package:reinhart1010_app/components/taskbar.dart' ('lib/components/taskbar.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'AdaptiveConstraints'.
```

Comment: I think you'll need to import another package: [`adaptive_components`](https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_components).

Comment: I also see that the `AdaptiveConstraints` class was defined separately in https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_breakpoints/example. But why should I reimplement the class if I could do that without this library?

Comment: @Apealed I've tried to installed both packages and it runs into dependency errors. But after fixing it, I still get that error.